# JavaScript function appearing in variable dump

Tags: javascript

Does anyone recognize this JavaScript function?

```
function (E,F){
var D=F||window;
var A=[];
for(var C=0,B=this.length;C<B;++C){
if(!E.call(D,this[C],C,this)){
continue
}
A.push(this[C])
}
return A
}
```

It seems like it's being inserted into a variable I'm trying to work with.  A few other JavaScript files and functions are being loaded, but I'm hoping someone can recognize this function before I have to list them here.

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what you're looking for. Read through the code to see what it does. It walks through an array, calls a method, and pushes the result into the return value if the call returns non-false. It is therefore a variation on Array.filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from [here:(I think it has something to do with twitter)](http://bennolan.com/science/newtwitter/base.txt)

```
Array.prototype.map = function(E, F) {
    var D = F || window;
    var A = [];
    for (var C = 0, B = this.length; C < B; ++C) {
        A.push(E.call(D, this[C], C, this))
    }
    return A
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I removed the TWTR widget code and the problem went away.